# Craft beers and Microbreweries in Singapore?

Tags: breweries, micropub, singapore

Recently, CNN listed the `Smith Street Tap` from the **Good Beer Company** in Singapore as one of the world's greatest bar (http://www.cntraveler.com/galleries/2015-07-21/the-greatest-bars-in-the-world/23).

Also, locally known, **Brewerkz** http://www.brewerkz.com/ serves some good craft beer.

After some internet searches, I found **Jungle Beer** that is a mircobrew: http://www.junglebeer.com/

Other than the 3 sources listed above, where else can one get craft/microbrewery beer in Singapore?

Are there other microbreweries in Singapore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Paulaner](http://www.paulaner-brauhaus.com/singapore)
[Reddot Brewhouse](http://reddotbrewhouse.com.sg/)
[Archepelago](http://www.archipelagobrewery.com/) (found in various locations)
[1925 Brewery](http://the1925.com.sg/)
[AdstraGold](http://adstragold.com/page60.html)

Paulaner should be the same everywhere, Reddot is pretty good, I'm not sure that Adstra actually exists (but WOW, what a janky website). Brewerkz still seems to be the best AFAIK.

Comment: I wish I read this before I went...!

Answer (score 2):

1. I can share a very nice experience at [**LeVeL33**](https://goo.gl/maps/X8GwPxLVn2Adjd4Q8) ([website](https://level33.com.sg/), [Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/level33_sg/)), which also claims to be *the world's highest urban microbrewery*, being located at floor 33 of MBFC Tower 1 in Marina Blvd, Singapore. Here, a glass of good house craft beer is not more expensive than a commercial pint in my hometown and foodies are also very good quality. The view over Marina Bay is even better than the beer.

[image: glass of craft beer]

2. The other one that I visited, serving good craft beers in Singapore in 2019, is [**Brewerkz Singapore**](https://www.instagram.com/brewerkzsg/).
3. Originally from Bangkok (Thailand), [**Tawandang Microbrewery**](https://www.facebook.com/Tawandang-Microbrewery-118856771508998/) has a restaurant-taproom in Dempsey Rd in Singapore.